# Socket.io js not connecting

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, socket.io, server

I have a node.js server running on the port 8443. Whenever I try to run the application through the browser my socket.io keeps connecting for about 20 seconds before the url turns red at the end.

Edit 3 : This is my directory structure and now with updated files

```
/var/www/html/nodetest/
```

Inside this

```
/node_modules
/app.js
/index.html
```

Node JS is installed on server.

Here is my main app.js code (as suggested in answer) :

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 var fs = require('fs');

  // Run server to listen on port 8443.
  server = app.listen(8443, () => {
   console.log('listening on *:8443');
 });

 io.listen(server);

 io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.emit('message', 'this is the message emitted by server');
  });   

 app.get('/', function(req, res){
   fs.readFile(__dirname + 'index.html', function(error, data) {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);         
   });
 });
```

And this is my client browser side code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1    
 /socket.io.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var websocket;
        function onload() {
        websocket = io.connect();
        websocket.on('message',function(data) {
           console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
        });

     };
   </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="onload()">
    <div id="divId"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is an image of the error

[image]

Now it shows 404 Error

Comment: What's the error it turns into?

Comment: @JustGameDev there is no error type showing . Its just try to connect for more than 20 seconds and after that the url turns into red.

Comment: Ports are different on server and client.

Comment: @ppovoski yes i tried changing it but its not working. Is there anything else on server side that may be refusing to connect.

Comment: Move `connect` and `disconnect` event from client to server. Those should be emitted by server not client.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad yes i will do that but my main concern is why the socket.io is not getting connect.

Comment: @ArthParikh, that is because once your server is up, its not emitting any events using `socket.io`. so any client can't connect to any port. as suggested move the code to server and that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified the code as per your need. The code is working as it is showing message emitted by server after loading in browser's console as in the below image.

Server.js:

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

let port = 8443;
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), function (error, data) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
});

// Run server to listen on port 8443.
http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`listning on ${port}`);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('message', 'this is the message emitted by server');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var websocket;
        function onload() {
            websocket = io().connect();
            websocket.on('message', function (data) {
                console.log('Received a message from the server!', data);
            });

        };
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onload();">

</body>
</html>
```

The out put is as below:[image]

Comment: what is the error or issue that you are facing? Can you edit your question with the updates that made?

Comment: Gaikwasd check now

Comment: @ArthParikh, I've modified the code as per your needs. The mistake in you code after modification was `__dirname+'index.html'` instead always make sure to use `path` module and combine the paths using `path.join`. Let me know if you're still getting any issues.

Comment: @ArthParikh, I just double checked the solution and it's working. Are you using the exact same code provided in the solution? Please provide the steps that you are using to run the app. can you please provide full error from console? Please check the network tab to get info exactly which file it is throwing error.

Comment: my script works to on localhost. The problem occurs when it comes to hosting side

Comment: Then check your permissions and try to load js files directly.

Comment: mail me at arparikh1010@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in a manner I haven't seen yet.  Here is an example that is working.  The main difference is my webserver returns the file that I am connecting with the socket.

**EDIT:** I updated this to use your webserver.  I modified it to make it make it server the index.html file.

Webserver:

```
   var app = require('express')();
   var server = require('http').createServer(app);
   var io = require('socket.io')(server);
   var fs = require('fs');

   // Run server to listen on port 8000.
   server = app.listen(8447, () => {
      console.log('listening on *:8447');
   });

   io.listen(server);

   io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.emit('message', 'this is the message emitted by server');
   });   

   app.get('/', function(req, res){
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(error, data) {
         res.writeHead(200);
         res.end(data);         
      });
   });
```

index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var websocket;
         function onload() {
            websocket = io.connect();
            websocket.on('connect',function() {
               console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
            });
            websocket.on('message',function(data) {
               console.log('Received a message from the server!',data);
            });
            websocket.on('disconnect',function() {
               console.log('The client has disconnected!');
            });
         };
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="onload()">
      <div id="divId"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you @ppovoski i tried your code. but now it throws 404 error for socket.io,js

Comment: Run `npm install socketio`.

Comment: Or replace my src line with your cloudflare line.

Comment: @ArthParikh, I added the connect and disconnect listeners and both are working.  Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two separate servers and only starting one of them so your socket.io server is never started.

Change this:

```
  var app = require('express')();
  var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  // Run server to listen on port 8000.
  server = app.listen(8447, () => {
   console.log('listening on *:8447');
  });
```

to this:

```
  var app = require('express')();

  // Run server to listen on port 8000.
  var server = app.listen(8447, () => {
   console.log('listening on *:8447');
  });
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

`app.listen()` creates its own server so you don't want to use both it and `http.createServer()`.

Here's the code for `app.listen()` so you can see how it works:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, you can see that the server you created with `http.createServer()` and then bound to socket.io was never started with `.listen()`.

Comment: i tried your solution but still it shows the same error as image added in my question.

Comment: @ArthParikh - Well, then you have some other issue you also have to fix because this was definitely the first thing you had wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You make a simple mistake. In your `html` file change socket.io library file source `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.5.1/socket.io.min.js` to socket.io cdn sorce which is `https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js`.

After that run restart you app.

if yo getting `404` again, then in you html replace `websocket = io.connect();` to `websocket = io.connect(your_server_domain_or_host_name:nodejs_server_running_port);`

Comment: see this answer [Hope it will be work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40624874/3176120) @arth-parikh

Comment: no i tried this solution still the url try to connect but not working.